# .htaccess file not rewriting url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

im trying to do a rewite but for some reason its not rewriting correctly. my structure is suppose to look like this `http://mysite.com/tv-show/showname/episode` instead its doing `http://mysite.com/tv-show/episode`

this is my code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tv-shows/(.*?)/(.*?)/ /index.php?name=$2 [NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It looks fine, is there anything im missing?

Comment: your examples say tv-show but your code says tv-shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tv-show(s?)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/? /index.php?name=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried your code and when I highlight my link it does give the structure i want however when I click it, it doesn't go to its page, it just refreshes the page.

Comment: can you share the link? or what you trying?